# How to make 3D hollow cuboid objects and cut holes out of it

Tags: modeling, objects

I am trying to create a very simple 3D model a hollow cuboid with specific holes cut into it. I have an illustrator vector file with the shapes I want to replicate in 3D but struggling to find tutorials to help me create it.

Any tips on where to start and which tools to use would be greatly appreciated. I have attached a few images below to explain what I am trying to achieve. One image is a 3D illustration and the other is the net of the 3D object.

[image: 3D illustration of the cuboid.]

[image: vector net of the 3D object.]

Comment: Can you provide the vector file so that we can understand from what you have to start with ?

Comment: If you have access to illustrator and the original file you could export it as SVG and import directly into blender. If you don't need a single object with a coherent continuous manifold mesh, it is as simple as extruding the imported bezier curve object's.

Comment: I did try the SVG import but I couldn't get the holes to extrude through the object? I can provide the vector file, everything above i have as vectors, such as the original shape in the middle with holes cut through it, i have that as a vector.

Comment: Seems like you are looking for the boolean modifier to cut the holes.

Answer (score 1):

You can model this object quite easily this with a *boolean modifier*, and 3 *array modifiers* as well as a *solidify modifier*.

As for the actual shape of the holes in the image posted in your question, you can do this with a cube that is subdivided twice, then bevel the edges with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> to round the shape and the mousewheel to adjust the cuts. Scale the object on the Z axis to finish it off.

For the rest of the object:

- Add a cube, scale on the x or y axis to the desired length,
  and apply scale with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>*Scale*. Then delete
  the faces at the ends with <kbd>X</kbd> in *edit mode*.
- In *object mode* add a *solidify modifier* to the cube, and adjust
  the thickness to the desired amount.
- Place your beveled cube where one of the holes should be. Scale it down accordingly.
- Add an *array modifier* to the small cube with an offset and count
  that is  appropriate across the top of the larger cube.
- Add a second *array modifier* to the small cube to move the copies to
  the opposite side.
- Add a third *array modifier* to move the first two to base, and apply
  all in the order they were added.
- Add a *boolean modifier* to the larger cube set to difference with
  the small cube as the target object and apply.

  You can delete the beveled cubes, they are no longer needed.

[image]